# How to make the height of an iframe flexible?

Tags: java, html, css

I want to show another web page inside my own web page with making some parts invisible.

I did it very good with this code

```
<div style="border: 0px solid #D5CC5A; overflow: hidden; margin: 15px auto; max-width: 300px;">
  <iframe scrolling="no"
          src="the site address" style="border: 0px none; margin-left: -3px; height: 9200px; margin-top: -50px; width: 300px;">
  </iframe>
</div>
```

---

As hight I took 9200px because I found that even the highest articles of the inner page would fit that.

The remaining problem is for example for the first page that it is a simple page not having any long articles so the iframe and my web page have a high scrollbar (9200px) even though the content is rather short!

How  can I tell the iframe only for the long pages to expand to the hight of 9200px?

For short pages the hight should be like 500px or something else.

Comment: It was rather hard to work this out but I'm 99% sure that this is what the original author wanted to say.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question very well. If you are trying to cut a section off the page in the iframe, your can't do it by defining height and width. iframe has to replicate the website you are trying to display through it exactly and so you can't hide elements on that page using iframe.

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

no i wrote this that you say ! and it worke - there it is :

```html
<html>
<body>
<  style="border: 0px solid #D5CC5A; overflow: hidden; margin: 15px auto; max-width: 300px;">
<iframe scrolling="no"
 src="https://stackoverflow.com" style="border: 0px none; margin-left: -3px; height: 9200px; margin-top: -50px; width: 300px;">
</iframe>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

but
 acctuly i want to make a condition for it

to say if the hight of page that i want showing inside my web

is to long fpr eaxample - hight=9000

my code in the section that i told befor (hight=9200)

changing the hight of my code that i wrote for you first to the

page hight (that i showing inside)